# Chords of the circumference in function of the radius

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

In the drawing, the circumference has center $O$ and radius $r$. If $MP=a$ and $PN=b$, and the sum of the arcs $AM$ and $NB$ is $90º$, then $a^2+b^2=?$

[image]

The only thing i discover is that the interior angles are $135º$ and $45º$, but nothing else. Any hints?

Comment: The "meta" way to answer this is to observe that the expression $a^2+b^2$ doesn't depend on the choice of $P$; therefore, let $P$ be a convenient point (say, at $O$ or on the circumference), and the calculation is trivial. Although this doesn't actually prove that $a^2+b^2$ is independent of $P$ (we're trusting the wording of the question), it gives you something to work towards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reflect $MN$ across $AB$ you get new chord $M'N'$ (which goes through $P$). Since $\angle MPN' = \angle MON'= 90^{\circ}$ we have cyclic quadrilateral $MPON'$ with diameter $MN'$. So by Pythagoras we have $$a^2+b^2 = MN'^2 =r^2+r^2 =2r^2$$